# missing linkers in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, fedora, owncloud

I have downloaded this project https://github.com/owncloud/sync-qt
next i did some modification to it.
I have added this files https://github.com/frankosterfeld/qtkeychain and sqlite3.h because of a missing libraries

Now the problem is that i have got those issues:

- error: cannot find -lqtkeychain
- error: cannot find -lsqlite3
- error:    cannot find -lkparts
- error: cannot find -lkdeui
- error: cannot find    -lkdecore
- error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

My OS is Fedora 18 64bit 
I am using Qt Creator 2.5.0 Based on Qt 4.8.2 (64 bit)

I think this error is that i have some missing linkers !! but i don't know how to fix that ??

Comment: I do not have any experience with Fedora, but the error message basically tells you that the linker cannot find `libqtkeychain.so`, `libsqlite3.so`, etc. Maybe you need to install those libraries (or dev-packets of those libraries).

Comment: sir @bjoernz please do you know how to do this ?? Because i didn't find any think that might help in the way how to install the missing libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the "linkers" which are missing, but some (development) *libraries* which are required to link the final executable (the linker takes the object files produced from your sources and all required libraries and links them together to produce the final executable file).

You need to make sure that the necessary -devel packages are installed - e.g. for the kde libraries, you need to install `kdelibs4-devel`. Since you have been able to *compile*  the sources, it seems like these packages are already available on your system (they also contain the `#include` files, so without them compilation would already fail).

It seems that fedora stores these libraries below /usr/lib/kde4/devel/ (or /usr/lib64/kde4/devel/) - check that these files are there (e.g. `/usr/lib64/kde4/devel/libkdecore.so`). If not, install the respective -devel package, like

```
# yum install kdelibs4-devel
```

Comment: I think they do not exist ! And for the others @Andreas ?? can you give me maybe a link or a way to fix that ?? i mean when i have a missing library is there a place where i can find it ???

Comment: now that did fixed 3 missing libraries but the 2 others i don't know in which devel package they are included @Andreas

Comment: I usually use google first in similar cases ;) There are also some rpm search sites, like http://rpm.pbone.net - the devel packages usually have the same (or a very similar) name as the corresponding runtime package, appended with -devel. In case of sqlite3, I found sqlite-devel on rpm.pbone.net

Comment: And, in case of `qtkeychain`, I suppose that you need to remove this library from your project since you have added the corresponding source files from git directly to your project, as far as I understand